# Variation of the Wave Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am concerned with solving the following PDE
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 u(z,t)}{\partial z^2} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\left[f(t) u(z,t)\right]
\end{align}

where $f$ is a periodic piecewise continuous function. Thank you to whoever can lead me toward a solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution? What kind of function is $f(t)$?

Comment: The function $f$ is a periodic piece wise continuous function. A general solution would be nice, but I am not so optimistic about finding one.

Comment: Right now, only thing one can do is give you a general solution... Have you tried separation of variables?

Comment: Yes I have attempted separation of variables but I get a discrepancy with the seperation constant for the time ODE; i.e it isn't constant. However, I may have made a mistake.

Comment: @Casey You can take the derivatives on the RHS, Fourier transform to get an ODE in $u$ with coefficients given by $f, f', f''$ and then put in Sturm-Liouville form (given that $f$ is continuous, even if piecewise). You can then solve the ODE and transform back.